# Merging audio with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession

I'd like to merge two audio files without too much overhead time. The following code successfully merges the audio but takes way too long (>30seconds for more than a couple minutes of audio), and I'm wondering if there is any way to expedite that process. I read in a couple places to use `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`, but I can't seem to get that preset to work with any file type. The only settings I've been able to get to work are using `AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A` and exporting as a `.m4a`

Code to create AVAssetExportSession

```
if (audioHasBeenRecorded) {
  // Merge recordings
  let composition = AVMutableComposition()
  let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

  guard let start = recorder.timeStart else { return }
  
  compositionAudioTrack?.insert(originalRecording: FileManagerHelper.recordingLocalURL(secondRecording: false), insertedRecording: FileManagerHelper.recordingLocalURL(secondRecording: true), startTime: CMTime(seconds: start, preferredTimescale: 1000000))

  if let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) {
    print(assetExport.supportedFileTypes)
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a
    assetExport.outputURL = FileManagerHelper.recordingLocalURL(secondRecording: false)
    do { // Delete old audio
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: FileManagerHelper.recordingLocalURL(secondRecording: false))
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: FileManagerHelper.recordingLocalURL(secondRecording: true))
    } catch { log(error.localizedDescription, msgType: .error) }
   
    assetExport.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
      if let error = assetExport.error {
        log(error, msgType: .error)
      } else {
        log("Successfully merged recordings!", msgType: .error)
        self.idea.numberOfPoints = self.audioVisualizer.count
        self.idea.save()
        
        self.setupPlayer() // Prepare to play the recorded audio file
        self.seekTo(TimeInterval((recorder.timeStart ?? 0) + (recorder.timeEnd ?? 0)))
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [ weak self ] in
          guard let self = self else { return }
          self.audioVisualizer.visualize(self.idea)
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Insert code:

```
extension AVMutableCompositionTrack {
  func insert(originalRecording: URL, insertedRecording: URL, startTime: CMTime) {
    let originalAsset = AVURLAsset(url: originalRecording)
    let insertedAsset = AVURLAsset(url: insertedRecording)

    let range1 = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: startTime)
    let range2 = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: insertedAsset.duration)
    let range3 = CMTimeRangeMake(start: startTime + insertedAsset.duration, duration: originalAsset.duration - startTime)
    if let originalTrack = originalAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first,
       let insertedTrack = insertedAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first {
         try? insertTimeRange(range1, of: originalTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
         try? insertTimeRange(range2, of: insertedTrack, at: startTime)
         try? insertTimeRange(range3, of: originalTrack, at: startTime + insertedAsset.duration)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you're looking in entirely the wrong place. To merge two audio files, use AVAudioEngine.

Comment: Hi matt, thanks for the suggestion. May I ask where to start looking in AVAudioEngine? It seems what I've found for AVAudioEngine relates to playback and I couldn't find anything on merging audio. Is the idea to start the playback of multiple audio files at scheduled times giving the effect of merging the audio?

Comment: AVAudioEngine is a programmatic sound mixer board, so it can merging multiple sounds is exactly what it is for. You can generate its output offline  as a new file (rather than playing the output live), and that is what you want to do. And yes, if different files start playing at different times, you get to schedule that.

Comment: You can see me playing around with AVAudioEngine here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p655AVAudioEngineTest/AVAudioEngineTest/ViewController.swift For your use case, look particularly at `doButton5`.

Comment: Wow, came across this resource while researching AVAudioEngine. Didn't know this was you. Thanks again! Really appreciate your help :)